Minimizing a function using matrix calculus
Consider the following:
$$
J = x^{\text{T}} \left(C^{\text{T}} K^{\text{T}} G K C - 2 A^{\text{T}} P_{k+1} B K C + P_k + Q - F \right) x
$$
where
\begin{align*}
x &\in \mathbb{R}^{n}, & C &\in \mathbb{R}^{q \times n}, & K &\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times q}, & G &\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}, & A,P,Q,F  &\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, & P &\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, & B &\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}
\end{align*}
With $G,~P,~Q, \text{and }F$ symmetric. Further, matrices $P \text{ and }G$ are positive definite, and $Q \text{ and } F$ are at least positive semidefinite.
I would like to minimize $J$ with respect to $K$ for any $x$. My thought is to take the first derivative of the terms within the parenthesis of $J$ with respect to $K$, set equal to the null matrix and solve for $K$. My problem is that I am unsure of how to take the derivative of the first and second terms (i.e., $ \frac{d}{dK}C^{\text{T}} K^{\text{T}} G K C \text{ and } \frac{d}{dK}2 A^{\text{T}} P_{k+1} B K C$). If these terms did not include the $C$ matrices, then I know the solution. However, I am unsure of how to take the derivative given that these $C$ matrices exist.
How do I take the derivative of these terms? Is there a better approach to minimize $J$ over $K$ that does not rely on derivatives?

The basic idea is to find $dJ(K)$ in terms of $dK$. I'll demonstrate for the first term $$J(K) = x^T C^T K^T G K Cx.$$
We have
\begin{align}
dJ(K) &= x^T C^T dK^T G K C x + x^T C^T K^T G dK C x \\
&= Tr(x^T C^T dK^T G K C x) + Tr(x^T C^T K^T G dK C x) \\
&= Tr(dK^T G K C x x^T C^T) + Tr(C x x^T C^T K^T GdK) \\
&= Tr(C x x^T C^T K^T G^T dK) + Tr(C x x^T C^T K^T GdK) \\
&= Tr((\nabla J(K))^T dK), 
\end{align}
where the last equation defines the gradient matrix $\nabla J(K)$.
Thus
$$\nabla J(K) = (G^T + G) K C x x^T C^T.$$
